# Why does the same TeX file and the same compiler generate different outputs on different machines?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I come across a weird issue:

My PC at office runs on Windows 10 professional; My notebook runs on Windows 10 Home. Both have installed TeX Live 2018.

The same TeX file, which `\includegraphics{test.png}`, generates two pdfs `pdf1` and `pdf2` on my PC and my notebook. The compiler options are same.

However, `pdf1` shows test.png with frame, while `pdf2` shows test.png without frame.

What's the root cause and how to avoid the differences?

Comment: `\includegraphics` never puts a frame around an image. In draft mode it makes a frame just with the file _name_.

Comment: Well something is different on your two PC. That can happen. But without code and log-files it is quite impossible to say what is going on in your case.